# add text to XML text TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to add text to a XML text field with this code. but im get this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'`

```
def has_Transp_Const(Rid):
    path = root.find('.//BUILDING/has_transp_const')
    if path.items() is None:
        path.text = '#{}' .format(str(Rid))
    else:
        path.text += ' #{}' .format(str(Rid))
```

XML i start with:

```
<BE>
    <BUILDING rid="#0">
        <has_transp_const/>
    </BUILDING>
</BE>
```

Wanted output:

```
<BE>
    <BUILDING rid="#0">
        <has_transp_const>#1 #2</has_transp_const>
    </BUILDING>
</BE>
```

It works fine when Im trying with this code:

```
OUT = ''
for i in range(10):
    if i == 0:
        OUT = '#{}' .format(str(i))
    else:
        OUT += ' #{}' .format(str(i))
print(OUT)
```

Comment: That error means ```path.text``` doesn't exist.

Comment: OUT is an empty string, so you can add to it; path.text is a NoneType value, not a string.

Comment: It makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `path.items()` in your example returns empty list so `path.items() is None` == `False` function goes to second condition and since path.text is None you get the exception.

Just change `path.items()` to `path.text`

```py
def has_Transp_Const(Rid):
    path = root.find('.//BUILDING/has_transp_const')
    if path.text is None:
        path.text = '#{}'.format(str(Rid))
    else:
        path.text += '#{}'.format(str(Rid))
```

Comment: Soo easy have been fighting with this the last hour or so... Thanks for the help